# nix-shell -p vs nix-env --attr

Tags: nixos, nix

Trying to understand nix package manager and some nixos.

What is `nix-env -attr` vs `nix-shell -p`?

I can do:

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.hello
```

But I need to use `-p` when using `nix-shell`:

```
nix-shell -p hello
```

And if it is some kind of evolvement in commands, is it then the reason for using `#` in `nix run` / `flakes`?